# Adding an entire working AngularJs 1.7 app to a Node.js Server

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a node.js server :

```
08/07/2019  17:52            14 545 app.js
06/07/2019  21:04    <DIR>          node_modules
06/07/2019  21:04            51 299 package-lock.json
06/07/2019  21:04               496 package.json
08/07/2019  17:53    <DIR>          public
08/07/2019  12:52    <DIR>          uploads
```

I have en entire angularJs website with a front end router that is working well, and is using the node app.js file as a back end for mongoDb, with some $http queries.

This angularJs website **is hosted on a external apache server**, and make calls to the node.js server through https using an angularjs service.

This is the angularJs app :

```
08/07/2019  17:57            15 398 app.js
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          bower_components
05/06/2019  15:59                70 cache.manifest
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          class
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          connexions
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          controllers
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          css
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          directives
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          img
08/07/2019  17:12            14 984 index.html
07/07/2019  20:51    <DIR>          js
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          librairies
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          libs
17/06/2019  19:45    <DIR>          mail
17/06/2019  19:40    <DIR>          myApp
17/06/2019  21:14    <DIR>          services
06/07/2019  20:36    <DIR>          tickets
07/07/2019  20:46    <DIR>          vues
```

Now, i have transfered the whole angularJs app to the node.js server PUBLIC directory.

But, when i type

```
node app.js
```

I can't see the angularJs app working, when browsing to

```
http://localhost:3000/public
```

I would really appreciate if somebody has an idea on how to make it work ?

How could I reach the angularJs website in one go, from the node.js server ? Is it possible ?

I don't want to redo all of the routes ! I don't need it, it is all done by the front end . I only need node.js to display the index.html and to run the whole front end app .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the thing is in `app.js` there.

You should add static routing in nodejs server config.

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Then, the nodejs server will serve angularjs's entry point - `public/index.html`.

Please refer to [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm trying out now